# Filtering arrays in JS/React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filtering

So here I have search functionality. Everything works fine except when an Item has not been found in the array. I have tried something with objects.Keys but it is displaying it on the render not when the Book has not been found like it should. Should I use if statement or.

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext}from 'react'
import {FaSearch} from 'react-icons/fa'
import { 
    Link, useHistory
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { BookContext } from '../../context/books';
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks';

const Search = () => {

  const {data}= useContext(BookContext)
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState('');
  const history= useHistory()
  const ref=useRef()

  function filterBooks(book) {
    console.log(book);
    if (!searchValue.length  ) return false;
    return book.bookName?.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  }

  const handleSearch = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
     setSearchValue('')
    }
  };
     
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleSearch);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleSearch);
    };
  }, []);
  

  
        return (
        <div className='search__cont' ref={ref}>   
              {Object.keys(data).filter(filterBooks).length === 0 &&(
           <div>
             <h3>Book not found</h3>
             </div>
         )}
           <SearchBooks searchValue={searchValue} setSearchValue={setSearchValue }/>          
           {Object.keys(data)
             .map((key) => data[key])
             .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [])
             .filter(filterBooks)
             .map((book) => {          
             return (
             <>       
              <div  className='search__books'
                onClick={() => {
                  history.push("/book/id", { book }); setSearchValue('')
                }}
               >            
                {" "}
                {book.bookName}{" "}
              </div>            
            </>
          );
        })}
           </div>
    )
}

export default Search
```

Comment: If you think this I forgot to remove it  ```if(!searchValue.length ) return book.bookName > 10``` .Thats my attempt that you shoved. I know that's the error

Comment: The issue is this. it is not displaying "no book has been found" when the search value is not found. I have like 10 components connected to each other. so Creating the sandbox would take me at least 20 min. If you don't know you don't know

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-pine-pbchq?file=/src/Search.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filtering the category names instead of the books (`data` is an object with category names as keys and books as values). You can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get an array of all the books and then apply the filter.

```js
const filteredBooks = Object.values(data).flat().filter(filterBooks)
const searchQueryPresent = searchValue.trim().length > 0
```

```
{
  searchQueryPresent &&
    (filteredBooks.length === 0 ? (
      <div>No books found</div>
    ) : (
      filteredBooks.map((book) => {
        return <>{/* render books */}</>
      })
    ))
}
```

[image: Edit on CodeSandbox]

Comment: filterBooks is return false  so that means, that items are not shown on first the render like I want. but in your case is true. So that means when It's false  I see book not found on the first render not when an item is not found

Comment: @mura1 You can render the book list or the "no books found" message only if the search query is present. Just updated my answer and the linked CodeSandbox.

Comment: Thank you. I know this not the question, but how would I lower the number of search values let's say to a max to 10. Right now If I type A word it is displaying a bunch of them

Comment: @mura1 You can use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to return a slice of the array. Just updated the CodeSandbox to give you an idea.